# Why is the data coming out weird in arduino code?

Tags: arduino, sensors

I want to get data from the sensor(I used velostat). And this is my code.

*Arduino Code*

```
#define numRows 1
#define numCols 1

int rows_out = 13;
int cols_in = 12;
int Values = 0;

void setup() {
  // set all rows and columns to INPUT (high impedance):
  pinMode(rows_out, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(cols_in, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  pinMode(cols_in, OUTPUT); // set as OUTPUT
  digitalWrite(cols_in, LOW); // set LOW

  Values = analogRead(rows_out); // read INPUT
  pinMode(cols_in, INPUT); // set back to INPUT!

  // Print the incoming values of the grid:
  Serial.println(Values);
  delay(1000);

}
```

I made a sensor with velostat. It has two cable.
I connected one of them with an analog pin of arduino board. And the other one with GND and other analog pin. like this.

**velostat cable 1 - analog pin 12**

**velostat cable 2 - analog pin 13 - GND**

But when I upload this program, weird data is coming out on serial monitor.

*Data displayed on serial monitor*

```
4095
4095
4075
3283
3082
3056
2973
2941
2865
2685
2308
1859
1365
```

If anyone knows the reason, please help me. I guess it is because connection of cable has problem or I connected wrong pin, but i'm not sure.

Comment: Velostat is basically a resistor that its resistance change subject to pressure applied. So you need to form a voltage divider by connecting a resistor between the Velostat and 5v, the other end of the Velostate simply connect to GND. If you understand this, then your code simply doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The data could be fine, you most possibly skipped the calibration step.

A velostat measures pressure, but depending on the materials used to make the sensor, its PressureIn-VoltageOut characteristic may differ greatly. Furthermore, differences exist even in sensors with the same build, thus the need for calibration is vital in applications that require precision.

I would suggest you assume a linear characteristic for simplicity's sake, and do the following 3-step calibration:

1. Average out 10 values for when there's nothing pressing on the sensor. That'd be your zero reference. We'll reference it as **X1**.
2. Press with the average expected pressure on the velostat and average 10 measurements again. That'd be your 'ON' reference, and we'll reference it as **X2**. This ON value needs an arbitrary numeric equivalent. I chose 15.

In math, it'd look like:
aX1 + b = 0
aX2 + b = 15

3. Once you solve for **a** and **b**, your **true** values would be represented by: a*[measuerement]+b.

P.S.: Sorry for the horrendous math formatting, still not familiar how to integrate math nicely in markdown.

Later edit: Higher precision can be achieved by averaging across more measurements AND picking a larger arbitrary value for the second equation (to have more granularity).

Comment: First of all, thank you for your kind answer.
However, I think there are some misunderstandings.

First of all, the reason I said it's weird is that the data has changed, regardless of pressing the 'velostat'.

Also, I understand that your formula is for smoothing the measurements. If I'm misunderstanding, can you explain it again?

Comment: Well... you didn't mention in the OP that you're not chaning the pressure level , now did you? Could be just sensor construction, if you used two copper sheets or some other homebrew build, it's fairly expected. Regarding the calibration method: only the averaging is for smoothing, while the `ax+b` thing is only there to shift measurements to a more meaningful scale (the meaning being, again, arbitrary).